# Issue with ruby parsing

Tags: html, ruby, arrays, parsing, nokogiri

Im just having a slight problem parising a website with nokogiri in ruby.

Here is what the site looks like

```
<div id="post_message_111112" class="postcontent">

        Hee is text 1 
     here is another
      </div>
<div id="post_message_111111" class="postcontent">

            Here is text 2
    </div>
```

Here is my code to parse it

```
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(myNewLink))
 myPost = doc.xpath("//div[@class='postcontent']/text()").to_a()

ii=0

 while ii!=myPost.length
     puts "#{ii}  #{myPost[ii].to_s().strip}"
   ii+=1
 end
```

My problem is when it displays it, because of the new line after `Hee is text 1`, the to_a puts it weird like so

```
myPost[0] = hee is text 1
myPost[1] = here is another
myPost[2] = here is text 2
```

I want each div to be its own message. like

```
myPost[0] = hee is text 1 here is another
myPost[1] = here is text 2
```

How would i solve this thanks

**UPDATED**

I tried

```
 myPost = doc.xpath("//div[@class='postcontent']/text()").to_a()

myPost.each_with_index do |post, index|
  puts "#{index}  #{post.to_s().gsub(/\n/, ' ').strip}"
end
```

I put post.to_s().gsub because it was complaining about gsub not being a method for post. But i still have the same issue. I know im doing it wrong just wrecking my head

**UPDATE 2**

Forgot to say that the new line is `<br />` and even with

```
   doc.search('br').each do |n|
  n.replace('')
end
```

or

```
doc.search('br').remove
```

The issue is still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the `myPost` array, you will see that each div is in fact its own message. The first just happens to include a newline-character `\n`. To replace it with a space, use `#gsub(/\n/, ' ')`. So your loop looks like this:

```
myPost.each_with_index do |post, index|
    puts "#{index}  #{post.to_s.gsub(/\n/, ' ').strip}"
end
```

**Edit:**

According to my limited understanding of it, xpath can only find nodes. The child nodes are `<br />`, so either you have multiple texts between them or you have the `div` tag included in your search. There sure is a way to join the texts between the `<br />` nodes, but I don't know it.
Until you find it, here something that works:

1. replace your xpath match with `"//div[@class='postcontent']"`
2. adjust your loop to delete the div tags:

   ```
   myPost.each_with_index do |post, index|
        post = post.to_s
        post.gsub!(/\n/, ' ')
        post.gsub!(/^<div[^>]*>/, '') # delete opening div tag
        post.gsub!(%r|</\s*div[^>]*>|, '') # delete closing div tag
        puts "#{index}  #{post.strip}"
   end
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but having just a small problem. after     myPost = doc.xpath("//div[@class='postcontent']/text()").to_a()...I Have.... myPost.each_with_index do |post, index|
    puts "#{index}  #{post.gsub(/\n/, ' ').strip}"
end.... But its giving out about no method gsub for post, so if i put...   myPost.each_with_index do |post, index|
      puts "#{index}  #{post.to_s().gsub(/\n/, ' ').strip}"
    end......it solves the no gsub issue but still same issue of the array

Comment: Excuse me, of course there was a `to_s` missing. I fixed it in the original, but now it prints each post in one line for me. I don't know what exactly is happening, could you provide a working example? The html you posted can't be parsed on its own.

Comment: <div id="post_message_222222" class="postcontent">
   text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. <br />
<br />
MAny thanks.
  </div>

Comment: I see, the difference seems to be the `<br />`. In your first example with a newline, everything works as intended, but not in your second example.

Comment: How do i fix this? Even if doc.search("//br").remove it still has the issue

Comment: added something that will help, although I don't like this solution

Answer (score 0):

Here, let me clean that up for you:

```
doc.search('div.postcontent').each_with_index do |div, i|
  puts "#{i} #{div.text.gsub(/\s+/, ' ').strip}"
end
# 0 Hee is text 1 here is another
# 1 Here is text 2
```